# Difference between two dates using Math

Tags: math

I have read a formula to determine the difference between two date using math with O(1) time complexity

`365*year + year/4 - year/100 + year/400 + (153*month - 457)/5 + day - 306`

with considering

> if month number less than 3 , year-=1 and month+=12

the following link show the whole code which i quote from

https://codeforces.com/contest/304/submission/3715756

So if someone can explain it please ?

Comment: What exactly is unclear for you?

Comment: (153*month - 457)/5 + day - 306 , This part actually

Comment: The `306` is irrelevant, and `(153*month-457)/5` is probably to take into account some Gregorian against another calendar.

Comment: you can ask the author of the code [here](https://codeforces.com/profile/kabar), if the code is not documented, thats what i would do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a full answer but it is some explanation.

First of all the

> if month number less than 3 , year-=1 and month+=12

is used to effectively start the year from March moving the highly irregular February to the end. Actually this is how this calendar was originally designed which you still can see in the names of some month like October or December (you probably hear that Oct = 8 and Dec = 10).

The `365*year + year/4 - year/100` beat is just handling the leap years.

The `day` part is also clear.

Now let's remove the bits that are irrelevant when we subtract two values and get this value for `month`

```
30*month + (3*month - 2)/5
```

I don't know the logic how it was got (I only have a guess at the end) but I can say why it works. The `30*month` bit is obvious. And now when we moved the February to its last position, all the month in the middle of the year have either `30` or `31` day. Let's write them down:

- Mar - 31 - +1
- Apr - 30 - +0
- May - 31 - +1
- Jun - 30 - +0
- Jul - 31 - +1
- Aug - 31 - +1
- Sep - 30 - +0
- Oct - 31 - +1
- Nov - 30 - +0
- Dec - 31 - +1
- Jan - 31 - +1

We don't care about February as there are no months after it (we cared about that before). We only care about this +1 day since the next month after that!

So what we need now is some formula that would match that distribution of `+1` and `+0`. And it appears that the value

```
(3*month - 2)/5
```

with integer division does exactly that. You can easily verify it by hand.

Probably the way to come up with this idea was to notice that the year (except for February) follows the following 5-month-cycle

+1 +0 +1 +0 +1

I mean March-July and August-December both match it exactly and then January is again +1 so it is like the first element of the next cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to write it formally:

```
f(y,m,d) = 365*y+ y/4 - y/100 + y/400 + (153*m- 457)/5 + d - 306
date_diff(y1,m1,d1,y2,m2,d2) = f(y1,m1,d1) - f(y2,m2,d2)
```

Simplifying:

```
date_diff = (y1-y2)*(365+1/4-1/100+1/400) + (m1-m2)*30.6 + (d1-d2)
```

And that makes sense because:

1. We have a leap year every 4 years, unless the year is divided by 100 and not 400.
2. The average amount of days in a month is ~30.6
3. All the weird magic numbers (306, and 457) go away

Comment: not saying that you are wrong, but in general integer aritmetics isnt that simple. You have to consider that `a/b + c/b` is not necessarily equal to `(a+c)/b`

Answer (score 0):

The only "funny" part is that if you compute `(153*m-457)/5` for the values from 3 to 15 you get

```
0, 31, 61, 92, 122, 153, 184, 214, 245, 275, 306, 337
```

where subtracting each element from the previous one starting from the second we get

```
31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31
```

that are the number of days in each month if we start from March

So the idea is: roll over so that the "strange" February month is the last one, count the years, leap days and days for passed months using the "magic" formula to get a clean number increasing by one for each day.

Subtracting two of these numbers gives the date difference.

PS: note that even a "regular" computation would be O(1)